# OpenVPN не пускает в инетрнет

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

Поставил OpenVPN по инструкции [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openvpn-ubuntu-16-04-ru). Но после подключения `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn` не пингует ни какие адреса кроме адреса сервера, хотя подключение проходит успешно. Трассировка так же заканчивается на сервере.

Куда можно копнуть? Я почти уверен, что косяк где-то на сервере, но где именно.

На сервере стоит Ubuntu, на клиенте - Arch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает в инструкции SNAT в фаерволе. Например:

```
iptabes -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: postrOuting   очепятка прокралась )

Comment: заюзал вот такое вот: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE, но не помогло

Comment: точно -o eth0 ?

Comment: Таки не eth0 оказалось, недосмотрел. Проблема как всегда решалась слишком просто, спасибо.